# Converting Excel to JSON

Tags: java, json, arrays

I have read an excel document using apache-poi.
The excel document which have records like:

```
A1 A2 A3 A4

A1 A2 B3 B4
```

i want to convert them into JSON arrays like

```
{ A1 : {A2 : {A3 : {A4 : some_value } } , {B3 : {B4 : some_value } } } }
```

Actually its easy to convert to XML.
Please tell me how to solve this. 
Only hints would suffice.

Comment: http://xstream.codehaus.org/json-tutorial.html

It should auto-generate what you're looking for:  Given a java class, it will give you a JSON text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can refer the following code:

```
FileInputStream inp = new FileInputStream( file );
Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create( inp );

// Get the first Sheet.
Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt( 0 );

    // Start constructing JSON.
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

    // Iterate through the rows.
    JSONArray rows = new JSONArray();
    for ( Iterator<Row> rowsIT = sheet.rowIterator(); rowsIT.hasNext(); )
    {
        Row row = rowsIT.next();
        JSONObject jRow = new JSONObject();

        // Iterate through the cells.
        JSONArray cells = new JSONArray();
        for ( Iterator<Cell> cellsIT = row.cellIterator(); cellsIT.hasNext(); )
        {
            Cell cell = cellsIT.next();
            cells.put( cell.getStringCellValue() );
        }
        jRow.put( "cell", cells );
        rows.put( jRow );
    }

    // Create the JSON.
    json.put( "rows", rows );

// Get the JSON text.
return json.toString();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot UVM :) I managed to solve the problem too

Answer (score 1):

After you get the data in Java objects you can create JSON using this simple JSON Library

http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

But you have to create those kind of structure in java object.