# ng repeat in table using Angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

The Array I use is `[{"cell":["jobcode","resume_number","score"]},{"cell":["jc100","rc1",80]},{"cell":["jc100","rc123",70]}]`

And I came up with javascript code as

```
var cell=response;
for (var i in cell) {
    for(var j in cell[i])
    {
        console.log(cell[i][j]);
        profiles.push(cell[i][j]);
        $scope.profiles=profiles;
        for(k in cell[i][j])
        {
            resumes.push(cell[i][j]);
            console.log("resume length"+resumes.length);
            $scope.columns=resumes;
            console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.columns));
        }
    }
}
```

And html is

```
<tr ng-repeat="profile in profiles track by $index" >
  <td ng-repeat="col in columns track by $index">
    <label >{{col.cell}}</label>
  </td>
</tr>
```

And ended up [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZe9t.png)

I have no idea to proceed further. I need to organize those data as a table. Please help.

Comment: Your array is not looks perfect

Comment: This array is actually the result of apache POI code to read excel file as json as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11343931/converting-excel-to-json

Comment: You want those data as table. Can you please explain a bit in detail? you want to get rid of JSON format there or just add new cells?

Comment: ok first object is display title of table right?

Comment: I have an excel file and I read it with apache poi and came up with json as mentioned. I need it like <tr><td>jobcode</td><td>resume_number</td><td>score</td></tr><tr><td>jc100</td><td>rc1</td><td>80</td></tr> This kinda. And yes, First displays title.

Comment: I want to use that json and display as a table. Three arrays form 3 rows and three elements in it form three columns,

Answer (score 0):

Your data contains an array of objects which contains another array. Therefore, you need to extract each object from outer array and then go down to inner one.

If you need this data only to organise them in a table, then you can simply use the following code:

Your Controller code:

```
$scope.cell = response;
```

Your HTML :

```
<tr ng-repeat="profile in cell track by $index" >
    <td ng-repeat="col in profile.cell track by $index">
        <label >{{col}}</label>
    </td>
</tr>
```

In case you need to store each array object, then you can use `forEach` loop:

Your controller code:

```
var cell=[{"cell":["jobcode","resume_number","score"]}, {"cell":["jc100","rc1",80]}, {"cell":["jc100","rc123",70]}];

angular.forEach(cell, function(data){
    $scope.profiles.push(data);
});
```

Your HTML :

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="profile in profiles track by $index" >
        <td ng-repeat="col in profile.cell track by $index">
            <label >{{col}}</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It is indeed the first one I have to do and that'll do. But it doesn't seem to work here..!

Comment: This is how your code should look like: [click here](http://i.imgur.com/u4RAFdI.jpg)

Comment: It was that "profile.cell" that didn't strike at all!! Brilliant!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code. Take header as separate part from json and display header first then start ng-repeat from `index first`

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>
            {{columns[0].cell[0]}}            
        </td>
        <td>
            {{columns[0].cell[1]}}            
        </td>
        <td>
            {{columns[0].cell[2]}}         
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr ng-repeat="col in columns" ng-if="$index>0">
        <td>
            {{columns[$index].cell[0]}}            
        </td>
        <td>
            {{columns[$index].cell[1]}}            
        </td>
        <td>
            {{columns[$index].cell[2]}}         
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I am in need of a generic code. Excel files I get would vary in number of columns.